# First scene won't disappear when second scene is called. Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to call my second scene and have the first disappear completely. The objects on the second scene are appearing, but they are overlapping those on the first scene. I've tried calling the scene.hide() and scene.destroy() functions manually and I've also tried adding objects to a group. Oddly enough, some of the objects weren't visible when added to a group, but others were. Please help! Also, sorry only some of the code is in the separate boxes, but I don't know how to  fix it!

```
function scene:create( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

    local group = display.newGroup()


    -------Set up green buttons
    local greenButton3=display.newImageRect("images/green-unclicked.png", 520,60)
    greenButton3.x=display.contentCenterX
    greenButton3.y=(970)
    greenButton3.button = 1

    local greenButton2=display.newImageRect("images/green-unclicked.png", 520,60)
    greenButton2.x=display.contentCenterX
    greenButton2.y=(870)
    greenButton2.button = 2

    local greenButton1=display.newImageRect("images/green-unclicked.png", 520,60)
    greenButton1.x=display.contentCenterX
    greenButton1.y=(770)
    greenButton1.button = 3
    --------SET UP RED BUTTONS
    local redButton1=display.newImageRect("images/red-dim.png",520,60)
    redButton1.x=display.contentCenterX
    redButton1.y=(40)
    local redButton2=display.newImageRect("images/red-dim.png",520,60)
    redButton2.x=display.contentCenterX
    redButton2.y=(140) 

    local redButton3=display.newImageRect("images/red-dim.png",520,60)
    redButton3.x=display.contentCenterX
    redButton3.y=(240)

    ---------------TEXT
    ---Questions
    local question1green=display.newText("How are you feeling?", 0,0,native.systemFontBold, 40)
    question1green.x=display.contentCenterX
    question1green.y=(705)

    local question1red=display.newText("The other person is feeling...", 0,0,native.systemFontBold, 40)
    question1red.x=display.contentCenterX
    question1red.y=(300)
    question1red.rotation = 180

    ---Answers
    --Green
    local answer1green=display.newText("Sad",0,0,native.systemFontBold, 40)
    answer1green.x=display.contentCenterX
    answer1green.y=(773)

    local answer2green=display.newText("Angry",0,0,native.systemFontBold, 40)
    answer2green.x=display.contentCenterX
    answer2green.y=(870)

    local answer3green=display.newText("I don't know",0,0,native.systemFontBold, 40)
    answer3green.x=display.contentCenterX
    answer3green.y=(973)

    --Red
    local answer1red=display.newText("Sad",0,0,native.systemFontBold, 40)
    answer1red.x=display.contentCenterX
    answer1red.y=(238)
    answer1red.rotation = 180

    local answer2red=display.newText("Angry",0,0,native.systemFontBold, 40)
    answer2red.x=display.contentCenterX
    answer2red.y=(141)
    answer2red.rotation = 180

    local answer3red=display.newText("Confused",0,0,native.systemFontBold, 40)
    answer3red.x=display.contentCenterX
    answer3red.y=(38)
    answer3red.rotation = 180

    --------CREATE EMPTY BODY OUTLINE
    local bodyOutline=display.newImageRect("images/bodyoutline.png", 380,560)
    bodyOutline.x=display.contentCenterX 
    bodyOutline.y=display.contentCenterY-10
    bodyOutline.rotation = 270

    --------move text to front after new buttons are created
    function moveTextToFront (event)
        answer1green:toFront()
        answer2green:toFront()
        answer3green:toFront()
        answer1red:toFront()
        answer2red:toFront()
        answer3red:toFront()
    end

    ------------------------------------------------------------
        --When the Buttons are Clicked
    ------------------------------------------------------------

    local function buttonClicked (event)
        print("here")
        --[[function destroyAll (event)
            greenButton1:removeSelf()
            greenButton1 = nil
            greenButton2:removeSelf()
            greenButton2 = nil
            greenButton3:removeSelf()
            greenButton3 = nil
            redButton1:removeSelf()
            redButton1 = nil
            redButton2:removeSelf()
            redButton2 = nil
            redButton3:removeSelf()
            redButton3 = nil
            print("destroyed")

            question1green:removeSelf()
            question1green = nil
            question1red:removeSelf()
            question1red = nil
            answer1green:removeSelf()
            answer1green = nil
            answer2green:removeSelf()
            answer2green = nil
            answer3green:removeSelf()
            answer3green = nil
            answer1red:removeSelf()
            answer1red = nil
            answer2red:removeSelf()
            answer2red = nil
            answer3red:removeSelf()
            answer3red = nil
            --]]
        --end
        --destroyAll()
        ------------------------------------------------------------
        --Start of Results Creation (SETUP)
        ------------------------------------------------------------
        function createGray1 (event)
            local gray1=display.newImageRect("images/grayRSU.png",520,60)
            gray1.x=display.contentCenterX
            gray1.y=(970)
        end

        function createGray2 (event)
            local gray2=display.newImageRect("images/grayRSU.png",520,60)
            gray2.x=display.contentCenterX
            gray2.y=(870)
        end

        function createGray3 (event)
            local gray3=display.newImageRect("images/grayRSU.png",520,60)
            gray3.x=display.contentCenterX
            gray3.y=(770)
        end

        function createGray4 (event)
            local gray4=display.newImageRect("images/grayUD.png",520,60)
            gray4.x=display.contentCenterX
            gray4.y=(240)
        end

        function createGray5 (event)
            local gray5=display.newImageRect("images/grayUD.png",520,60)
            gray5.x=display.contentCenterX
            gray5.y=(140)
        end

        function createGray6 (event)
            local gray6=display.newImageRect("images/grayUD.png",520,60)
            gray6.x=display.contentCenterX
            gray6.y=(40)
        end

        function firstClicked (event)
            local greenClicked1=display.newImageRect("images/green-clicked.png",520,60)
            greenClicked1.x=display.contentCenterX
            greenClicked1.y=(970)

            local redClicked1=display.newImageRect("images/red-clicked.png",520,60)
            redClicked1.x=display.contentCenterX
            redClicked1.y=(240)
        end

        function secondClicked (event)
            local greenClicked2=display.newImageRect("images/green-clicked.png",520,60)
            greenClicked2.x=display.contentCenterX
            greenClicked2.y=(870)

            local redClicked2=display.newImageRect("images/red-clicked.png",520,60)
            redClicked2.x=display.contentCenterX
            redClicked2.y=(140)
        end

        function thirdClicked (event)
            local greenClicked3=display.newImageRect("images/green-clicked.png",520,60)
            greenClicked3.x=display.contentCenterX
            greenClicked3.y=(770)

            local redClicked3=display.newImageRect("images/red-clicked.png",520,60)
            redClicked3.x=display.contentCenterX
            redClicked3.y=(40)
        end
        ------------------------------------------------------------
        --End of Results Creation (SETUP)
        ------------------------------------------------------------
        --local function sceneDone (event)


        --end
            -------------------------
            --transition to next scene IN THIS FUNCTION
        if (event.target.button == 1) then
            greenButton1:removeSelf()
            greenButton1 = nil
            greenButton2:removeSelf()
            greenButton2 = nil
            greenButton3:removeSelf()
            greenButton3 = nil
            redButton1:removeSelf()
            redButton1 = nil
            redButton2:removeSelf()
            redButton2 = nil
            redButton3:removeSelf()
            redButton3 = nil
            firstClicked()
            createGray2()
            createGray3()
            createGray5()
            createGray6()
            --composer.removeScene("firstscene")

        end
        if (event.target.button == 2) then
            greenButton1:removeSelf()
            greenButton1 = nil
            greenButton2:removeSelf()
            greenButton2 = nil
            greenButton3:removeSelf()
            greenButton3 = nil
            redButton1:removeSelf()
            redButton1 = nil
            redButton2:removeSelf()
            redButton2 = nil
            redButton3:removeSelf()
            redButton3 = nil
            secondClicked()
            createGray1()
            createGray3()
            createGray4()
            createGray6()

            --composer.removeScene("firstscene")
        end
        if (event.target.button == 3) then
            greenButton1:removeSelf()
            greenButton1 = nil
            greenButton2:removeSelf()
            greenButton2 = nil
            greenButton3:removeSelf()
            greenButton3 = nil
            redButton1:removeSelf()
            redButton1 = nil
            redButton2:removeSelf()
            redButton2 = nil
            redButton3:removeSelf()
            redButton3 = nil
            thirdClicked()
            createGray1()
            createGray2()
            createGray4()
            createGray5()

            --composer.removeScene("firstscene")
        end
        moveTextToFront()
        composer.gotoScene("secondscene")
    end

    greenButton1:addEventListener("touch", buttonClicked)
    greenButton2:addEventListener("touch", buttonClicked)
    greenButton3:addEventListener("touch", buttonClicked)
end --end of images and stuff

function scene:show( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if phase == "will" then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen and is about to move on screen
    elseif phase == "did" then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen
        -- 
        -- INSERT code here to make the scene come alive
        -- e.g. start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
    end 
end

function scene:hide( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase
        print("hidden2")
    if event.phase == "will" then
        -- Called when the scene is on screen and is about to move off screen
        --
        -- INSERT code here to pause the scene
        -- e.g. stop timers, stop animation, unload sounds, etc.)
    elseif phase == "did" then
        print("hidden")
        -- Called when the scene is now off screen
    end 
end

function scene:destroy( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    -- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (sceneGroup)
    -- 
    -- INSERT code here to cleanup the scene
    -- e.g. remove display objects, remove touch listeners, save state, etc.

    if playBtn then
        playBtn:removeSelf()    -- widgets must be manually removed
        playBtn = nil
    end
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see in your code that you are adding your object into the `sceneGroup` (`self.view`). Make sure you insert them into that group for example `scneeGroup:insert( greenButton3 )`.

When changing scene there is no need to hide the objects in the `sceneGroup` as they will be hidden automatically by Corona.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all the display objects in to the sceneGroup.

```
function scene:create( event )
local sceneGroup = self.view

display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

local group = display.newGroup()


-------Set up green buttons
local greenButton3=display.newImageRect("images/green-unclicked.png", 520,60)
greenButton3.x=display.contentCenterX
greenButton3.y=(970)
greenButton3.button = 1
sceneGroup :insert(greenButton3)
end
```

try adding all the text objects everything in to the sceneGroup.